# Source code for graphsim

Tags: programming, resource-request

The source code for the graph state simulator from ["Fast simulation of stabilizer circuits using a graph state representation"](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0504117) is supposed to be at http://homepage.uibk.ac.at/homepage/c705/c705213/work/graphsim.html but the link is dead and the WayBack machine did not archive it.

Does anyone know where another copy can be found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be a copy on GitHub at https://github.com/marcusps/GraphSim